# What is the best approach to download content using REST api's containing large data(100 MB) - Java

Tags: java, rest, download, iostream

I used Mapr Apis to read the content from log file into Stream object.

// Code to read log file ........
// Then got the content into Stream object as shown below.

FSDataInputStream stream = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri),conf);

// Now I have make this content available in UI for download.

// I can convert this to byte[] and then to String as

byte[] bs = new byte[stream.available()];

String content  = new String(bs);

My requirement is to create a Rest Api to download this content. What is the best approach to download this content?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add relevant code to go with your question what you tried here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/download/{id}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)  
 public ResponseEntity<?> downloadReportFile(@PathVariable Long id) {
    log.debug("To download log file from remote server.");

    try {
        Long idparam = id;
       // -----------------------
       // Code to get FSDataInputStream
       // -----------------------  
       FSDataInputStream stream =FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri),conf);
       byte[] byteArray = new byte[stream.avilable()];
       stream.read(byteArray)
        return new  ResponseEntity<>(new ByteArrayResource(byteArray), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Failed to download file ", e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
    }

}
```